# error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol virtual class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, virtual, abstract-class

I know this question was asked several time, but i don't find how to resolve it.

I get this error when i'm trying to build my project:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall IGameState::~IGameState(void)" (??1IGameState@@UAE@XZ) in function "public: virtual __thiscall MenuState::~MenuState(void)" (??1MenuState@@UAE@XZ)
```

Here is my code:

**IGameState.h**

```
class IGameState
{
    public:
        virtual ~IGameState();
        virtual void update() = 0;
        virtual void render() = 0;
};
```

**MenuState.h**

```
#include "IGameState.h"

class MenuState : public IGameState
{
public:
    MenuState();
    ~MenuState();
    void update();
    void render();
};
```

**MenuState.cpp**

```
#include "MenuState.h"

#pragma region Constructor

MenuState::MenuState() {

}

MenuState::~MenuState() {

}

#pragma endregion


void MenuState::render() {

}

void MenuState::update() {

}
```

What's wrong with the destructor?
Thanks.

Comment: You haven't defined it, only declared. That's enough for compiler, but not for linker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message tells you that's a link error, because you haven't implemented `~IGameState()`,
Try add below code:

```
class IGameState
{
    public:
        virtual ~IGameState() {} 
                            //^^^^ define it
        virtual void update() = 0;
        virtual void render() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not figure that virtual function need to be implemented.

Comment: @bilz what is the point of defining destructorfor purely abstract class?

Comment: @saurabheights that's C++ : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336499/virtual-desctructor-on-pure-abstract-base-class